# Include non related collection in model result

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm new to MongoDb and Mongoose and this might sound silly but I'm a bit confused about how things work.

I have two unrelated models: `page` model and `team` model that looks something like this:

```
// page.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.schema({
  name: String,
  body: {
    title: String,
  },
});
const Page = mongoose.model('Page', schema);

export default Page;
```

and

```
// team.js

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.schema({
  name: String,
  position: Number,
});
const Team = mongoose.model('Team', schema);

export default Team;
```

What I want to do is when I find one page (`Page.findOne({...})`) to include all teams. The result will look like this:

```
{
  _id: 'some_id',
  name: 'some name',
  body: {
    title: 'A title',
    teams: [
      { name: 'Team1', position: 1 },
      { name: 'Team2', position: 2 },
      // ...
      { name: 'Team3', position: 3 },
    ],
  },

}
```

I looked at `populate` but this requires refs to other model.
Looked at `virtuals` but from what I understand this should work only with instance properties.

What will be the best approach to achieve this without adding relations between the two models?

This is I'm currently doing:

```
const pageResult = await Page.findOne({});
let page = pageResult.toObject();
page.body.team = await Team.find({});
```

Answer (score 0):

well with out referencing, the only way to do that is to manually query Page model and **findOne()** what is the doc you want and then inside the callback of that findOne(), you will have to get Teams you desire with the value of Page.body.title value.

But its very easy to use Ref and populate using mongoose but if this is the way you really want to go knock yourself out mate ... :) cheers ...

```
Page.findOne({_id:req.body.id},(err,page)=>{
    if(!err){
        team.find({},(err,teams)=>{ // this will give you an array of teams 
            if(!err){
                   page.body.teams = teams; // this line set teams array from this callback to previous findOne()'s page obj
                                      //so that you will finally create the object you want             
            }else{
                throw err;
            }
        });
    }else{

    }
});
```

since you have only 2 fields in team model I think you won't be needing to use projections

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm doing something similar to your answer. Just a note  `page.body.title` is not the same as `team.title`. I updated my question to reflect this. I don't want add refs because these models have nothing related, besides I need team collection to be part of page results in only when I'm fetching one page.

Comment: I want to include all team documents

Comment: oh , so you can just use find() and use projections to check filter only the fields you want to bring

Comment: Your solution will not work because mongoose result are immutable. You cannot add extra fields to page.body. I updated my question with what I'm doing.

Comment: then may be try creating a separate object that is not immutable and add team ?